# How do I modify Darcula error highlights in IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I love the [Moonrise UI](http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/) theme for Eclipse. However I have grown less fond of Eclipse and am trying to switch to IDEA. One of the things I miss most though with the Moonrise theme is how nicely it highlights compile errors and warnings. It highlights the text background red and yellow respectively.

[image]

Errors and warnings in IDEA's Darcula theme, however, are not so obvious.

[image]

How do I modify the Editor pane colors in IDEA to format errors/warnings exactly like Eclipse Moonrise and highlight the background red/yellow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Editor/Colors and Fonts*. If you haven't modified the theme before, save it first using *Save As...* button, because you can't modify the default one.

Then go to *General* and find *Error* and *Warning* items in the list. Uncheck the *Error Stripe Mark* and *Effects* checkboxes and check the *Background* checkbox. You can then select the color by clicking on the color selector next to the checkbox.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you! It is always the little things that increase usability, and this will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to "Error" also "Unknown symbol" should be formatted.